# Update database (mdb) problem using python: Datatype is datetime but require float when using UPDATE

Tags: python

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFxBz.png)

I got a problem when I try to use UPDATE to update my database. My table has 6 columns (datatype are str, datetime, int, int, float, and int, respectively). I write a python command as follow:

cur.execute("UPDATE DISCHARGE1 SET DataValue=200, flag=1 WHERE Station='12345' and DataDate='12/16/2021' and DataHour=1 and DataMinute=0")

then I got error:
cur.execute("UPDATE DISCHARGE1 SET DataValue=200, flag=1 WHERE Station='12345' and DataDate='12/16/2021' and DataHour=1 and DataMinute=0")
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I checked and realized the problem is in the datatype of DataDate column. I then remove ' ' and the code run without error but nothing is updated. Despite the datatype of the DataDate column is datetime, the datatype required in "UPDATE" line is float. Somebody help me

Comment: Please have a look here to improve your chances of getting an answer: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To update your datas you need to commit with `connection.commit()` after your `cur.execute`

Documentation :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html

Edit:
Have you tried to send the date like this

```
DataDate=Format('12/16/2021', "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm")
```

or

```
DataDate=DateValue('12/16/2021')
```

Comment: it worked when i try: DataDate=DateValue('12/16/2021'). Thank you very much